# Is this question about the PCP theorem appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am a mathematician who is working toward understanding a proof of the PCP theorem. I am reading Arora and Barak's book *Computational Complexity*, and I've noticed what I think are a few errors (in the published book). My question is basically if I am correct that what I found are errors and if my fixes are correct. I'm guessing this is a graduate level question, but it isn't research level. So I first posted it [here at cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/130869/on-the-usage-of-arora-and-baraks-main-lemma-in-their-proof-of-the-pcp-theorem) about a week ago, but I think there are more people here who could answer it.

> Is the linked question appropriate for cstheory.stackexchange?

---

EDIT: Because two moderators said that it is appropriate, I [posted the question here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47721/on-the-usage-of-arora-and-baraks-main-lemma-in-their-proof-of-the-pcp-theorem).

Comment: Seems like a great question to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a question is appropriate for this site -- I think of graduate-level questions in TCS as on-topic.  (ps Arora-Barak does have a lot of errors!)